# Почему не отправляется письмо из формы через phpmailer

Tags: php, форма, email, phpmailer

помогите пожайлуста разобраться в чём проблема.
Почему не отправляется письмо из формы через phpmailer?
До этого пробовал через встроенную функцию mail(),работало,но были проблемы с отправкой файла,решил попробовать phpmailer.
В итоге письмо не отправляется остаётся висеть пустая страница и ошибок не выводит(до этого пробовал через try/catch).

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/*код*/

require '../phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('ru', '../phpmailer/language/');
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['first_name']);
$mail->addAddress('contactus@anreyz.tmweb.ru');
$mail->Subject = 'Заявка';

$gender = "male";
if ($_POST['gender'] == "female") {
    $gender = "female";
}

$chb = $_GET['chb'];
$new_cnb = implode(",", $chb);


//Тело письма
$body = '<h1>Составленная заявка</h1>';

if (trim(!empty($_POST['first_name']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Имя:</strong>' . $_POST['first_name'] . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['last_name']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Фамилия:</strong>' . $_POST['last_name'] . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['email']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Почта:</strong>' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['gender']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Пол:</strong>' . $gender . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['cnb']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Навыки:</strong>' . $new_cnb . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['developer']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Должность:</strong>' . $_POST['developer'] . '</p>';
}

if (trim(!empty($_POST['content']))) {
    $body .= '<p><strong>Должность:</strong>' . $_POST['content'] . '</p>';
}

if (!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    //путь загрузки файла
    $filePath = __DIR__ . "../images/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
    //грузим файл
    if (copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
        $fileAttach = $filePath;
        $body .= '<p><strong>Фото в приложении</strong></p>';
        $mail->addAttachment($fileAttach);
    }

}

$mail->Body = $body;

$mail->send();

/*код*/
?>
```

Comment: `$mail->IsHTML(true);` должно располагаться после `$mail->Body = $body;`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Увы не помогло

Comment: А без формы PHPMailer работает, отправляет письма?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Нет, всё также не отправляет.

Comment: странно, должны быть какие-то ошибки, логи... Я бы вам советовал убрать из вопроса всю ерунду с формой и написать простой пример с 5-ю строчками кода, в которых попытка отправить тестовое письмо через PHPMailer. Так больше шанс, что кто-то ответит.